# Why is a @SpringBootTest unable to auto wire a @TestComponent?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I have an integration test with a dependency on a test component:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CarRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
    
    @Autowired 
    private CarTestHelper carTestHelper;

    @Autowired
    private Login login;

    @Test
    public void testReportData() throws SQLException {
        
        // calls a stored procedure without txn
        sessionRepository.getSession(login.getUser(), login.getPassword());
        
        LocalDate july5Of2016 = LocalDate.of(2016, 7, 5);
        byte[] reportData = carTestHelper.getCarData("VIN1234", july5Of2016)
        
        assertThat(reportData, notNullValue());
        assertThat(reportData.length, lessThanOrEqualTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
```

Here's the `@TestComponent` that is not found by Spring (in the same package):

```
@TestComponent
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CarTestHelper {
    
    private final CarRepository carRepository;
    
    //MUST DO THIS HERE b/c @SpringBootTest ignores Propagation.NEVER on @Test method
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER,  transactionManager ="carTransactionManager")
    public byte[] getCarData(String vin, LocalDate date) throws SQLException {
        Blob reportData = carRepository.getReportData(vin, date);
        byte[] reportDataBytes = reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte a : reportDataBytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", a));
        }

        log.debug("Number of bytes: " + reportDataBytes.length);
        log.debug("Number of bytes: " + reportData.length());
        
        return reportDataBytes;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in different package you might need to explicitly import it, i.e.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(CarTestHelper.class)
public class CarRepositoryTest {
   ...
}
```